# volver atras con react

Tags: reactjs

estoy para un proyecto generando un detalle de producto de una "tienda de musica", hasta ahora lo tenemos como volver atras hacia el home (donde presentamos algunos de los productos renderizados) la cuestion esta en que queremos que al hacer clik en volver nos devuelva a la pagina anterior DESDE la que selecciono el producto (ya sea el home como hasta ahora, como asi tambien a la pagina de productos con o sin filtros aplicados)

como me sugieren modificar este sector

```
<div className={styles.flechaDerecha}>
        <Link to="/">← Volver</Link>
      </div>
```

sin que me rompa todo???
gracias de antemano